# "access_denied" when using Yahoo OAuth

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-identity-2, yahoo-oauth

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application which was migrated to ASP.NET Identity and I am in the progress of implementing OAuth authentification. Before the migration I was using Yahoo with OpenID which did work, but is no longer supported.
All common provider (Google, MS, Facebook, ...) are working fine, but I can't get Yahoo to work.
I am using the [THIS](http://www.beabigrockstar.com/blog/introducing-the-yahoo-linkedin-oauth-security-providers-for-owin/) provider.

When I do the authentication everything looks fine until it comes back to my page. There `await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync()` returns null.

I then checked the complete "request stack" and saw the following "request-flow":

1. Post back to `http://mydomain.net/Account/ExternalLogin`
2. Response with header `Location: https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth?oauth_token=hwwvmgr`
3. Loging in via Yahoo
4. Request to `https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth`
5. Response with header `Location: http://mydomain.net/signin-yahoo?oauth_token=hwwvmgr&oauth_verifier=p2bppu`
6. Request to that URL
7. Response with header `Location: /Account/ExternalLoginCallback?error=access_denied`

*Does anybody have an idea why this could happen?*

I executed this on a "real domain" which is verified at Yahoo.
The Configuration looks like the following:

```
var options = new YahooAuthenticationOptions();
options.ConsumerKey = settings.ConsumerKey;
options.ConsumerSecret = settings.ConsumerSecret;
app.UseYahooAuthentication(options);
```

Comment: My colleague was having similar difficulties with yahoo. I'll ask him to review your question tomorrow.

Comment: @spender: I already found it - see my answer, but thanks anyhow...

Comment: Great news. Maybe there's something for him to see here, so thx for self-answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: Was a bug in the provider.
If you check the History [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Owin.Security.Providers/):

> Version 1.5.1
>         - Fixed issue with Yahoo provider. Please see http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/introducing-the-yahoo-linkedin-oauth-security-providers-for-owin for how to use the Yahoo provider correctly. Take note of the requirements for testing on localhost.

I just updated the provider to version 1.6 (they just came out last week, so I had not updated yet) and it is working now.

Comment: That link (above) is a dead end.  I think the  link your after is http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/introducing-the-yahoo-linkedin-oauth-security-providers-for-owin